# Numerus-Kongruenz bei Parenthese

Tags: grammatical-number, parenthesis

Bei einem Satz wie

> Er und ich sehen das Ding.

ist der Plural völlig gerechtfertigt und natürlich. Aber wie schaut es aus, wenn die Hälfte des Subjekts nur eingeschoben ist?

> Er – und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung letztlich auch ich – sehen das Ding.

Einerseits *hört* sich das mit dem Plural immer noch besser an als jedweder Singular; andererseits sollte das Auslassen einer Parenthese normalerweise nichts kaputt machen, was hier aber geschieht:

> Er [...] sehen das Ding. ?

Was ist zu empfehlen?
(Und weil "Er", "sehen", "ich" und "Ding" gegenüber meinem Anwendungsfall ziemlich eingedampft sind, bitte von Umformulierungswünschen a la

> Er sieht das Ding – und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlcher Ablenkung sehe ich es letztlich auch.

soweit nur irgend möglich absehen)

Comment: Sind Beginn und Ende der Parethese so festgelegt (und überhaupt richtig)? Vielleicht "Er und - bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung letztlich auch - ich sehen das Ding."?  Oder - auch wenn Du keine Umformulierungungen wünschst - "Er - und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung trifft das letztlich auch auf mich zu - sieht das Ding." Wenn das Beispiel in der Frage vereinfacht ist, wäre vielleicht doch das kompliziertere Beispiel hilfreich.

Comment: Die Definition einer Parenthese ist i.a. "ein Einschub, der innerhalb eines Satzes vorkommt, aber nicht in seine syntaktische Struktur integriert ist", oder auch "nicht in die grammatische Struktur des Satzes integriert ist". Der erste Teil der Definition trifft in deinem Beispiel zu, der zweite wohl eher nicht - Dadurch, dass er das Subjekt in den Plural erhebt, ist er sehr wohl "in die syntaktische Struktur des Satzes integriert" - zwar nicht vollständig, aber durchaus erheblich, ist also folglich keine Parenthese. Daher ist wohl auch deine Schlußfolgerung unzulässig.

Comment: Der Begriff, den du suchst, heisst *Hyperbaton*. (Dort gibt es keine Bedingung für "syntaktische Nichtintegration".) Für das gilt die Bedingung "Weglassen ändert am Satz nix" eben nicht.

Comment: Ist das in dem Beispiel Angeführte überhaupt eine (echte) Parenthese? Denn letztlich ist doch "er und [...] ich" eben NICHT *nicht in die syntaktische Struktur integriert*, sondern sehr wohl integriert - das ist einfach eine nähere Bestimmung von "ich", wie @Bodo sehr richtig bemerkt. Der "Kernsatz" lautet: "Er und ich sehen das Ding." und da ist der Plural völlig normal und folgerichtig.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde tatsächlich genau aus dem von Dir genannten Grund den Singular benutzen, wie man es auch in dieser Umstellung tut:

> Er sieht das Ding, und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung letztlich auch ich.

Die Bezeichnung der Konstruktion als *Hyperbaton*, was einfach nur ein Oberbegriff ist, ändert daran aus meiner Sicht nichts, es bleibt ja trotzdem eine Paranthese.

Stilistisch hässlich bleibt es trotzdem, deshalb empfielt sich letztlich doch eine Umformulierung.

Wie auch in der obigen Umstellung gilt für die Paranthese, dass die hauptsächliche Feststellung der Satzes ist, dass "er das Ding sieht", und das andere grammatisch nur eine Ergänzung dazu, nichts Gleichwertiges. Wenn es als gleichwertig gedacht ist, ist die Paranthese aus meiner Sicht einfach die falsche Konstruktion, dann wäre es vielleicht so sinnvoller:

> Er und, bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung, letztlich auch ich sehen das Ding.

Answer (score 1):

Du kannst die Ausklammerung um das Verb kürzen:

- Original: Er – und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung letztlich auch ich – **sehen** das Ding.
- Vorschlag: Er **sieht** – und bei genauer Betrachtung und nach umfangreicher textlicher Ablenkung letztlich **sehe** auch ich –  das Ding.